# Qt/C++ -- Update UI from another class

Tags: c++, qt

I have a project to do using Qt and C++. For that first, I need to create a sample Client-Server program. Using Qt Creator, I have designed the Ui and written some code for connecting and reading messages, etc.

But, I'm unable to update the UI for program from the server class.

What should I do to make it right ?

### mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtGui>
#include "serverwin.h"
#include <QtNetwork>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void connectClicked();
    void disconnectClicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

### serverwin.h

```
#ifndef SERVERWIN_H
#define SERVERWIN_H

#include <mainwindow.h>
#include <QtNetwork/QTcpServer>
#include <QtNetwork/QTcpSocket>



namespace server{
class MainWindow;
}

class ServerWin : public QTcpServer
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        ServerWin(QObject* parent);

    protected:
        void incomingConnection(int socketfd);

    private slots:
        void readyRead();
        void disconnected();

    private:
        QSet<QTcpSocket*> clients;
};

#endif // SERVERWIN_H
```

### main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "serverwin.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    MainWindow *uiwindow = new MainWindow();

    uiwindow->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

### mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_server.h"
#include "serverwin.h"
#include "QtNetwork/QTcpSocket"


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{            
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ui->disconnectButton->setEnabled(false);
}

void MainWindow::connectClicked()
{
    ui->connectButton->setEnabled(false);

    ui->disconnectButton->setEnabled(true);

    bool success = serv->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 4200);

    if(!success)
    {
        ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText("Could not connect to port 4200, check your firewall settings.");
    }
    else
    {
        ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText("Connected");
    }
}

//close server request by user

void MainWindow::disconnectClicked()
{
    ui->disconnectButton->setEnabled(false);

    ui->connectButton->setEnabled(true);

    ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText("doesn't work, code to be added");
    //disconnect server
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

### serverwin.cpp

```
#include "serverwin.h"

ServerWin::ServerWin(QObject *parent)
{
}

void ServerWin::incomingConnection(int socketfd)
{
    QTcpSocket *client = new QTcpSocket(this);

    client->setSocketDescriptor(socketfd);

    clients.insert(client);

    qDebug() << "Client " + client->peerAddress().toString() + " is connected.";

    connect(client, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyRead()));

    connect(client, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(disconnected()));
}

void ServerWin::readyRead()
{
    QTcpSocket *client = (QTcpSocket*)sender();

    while (client->canReadLine())
    {
        QString msg = "Client " + client->peerAddress().toString() + " says: "  + QString::fromUtf8(client->readLine()).trimmed();

        foreach (QTcpSocket *otherClient, clients)
            otherClient->write(QString(msg + "\n").toUtf8());

        qDebug() << msg;
    }
}

// when a client is disconnected

void ServerWin::disconnected()
{
    QTcpSocket *client = (QTcpSocket*)sender();

    clients.remove(client);

    QString notification = "Client " + client->peerAddress().toString() + " has Left.";

    foreach (QTcpSocket *otherClient, clients)
        otherClient->write(QString(notification + "\n").toUtf8());

    qDebug() << notification;
}
```

The debug lines need to updated in the GUI where I have a text box (plaintextedit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to make member functions in your window class, which will b responsible for outputting your text. For example,

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
<...>
public slots:
    <...>
    void displayMessage( const QString & message );
}
```

Now, in this function, you can access the UI, for example:

```
void MainWindow::displayMessage( const QString & message )
{
    ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText( message );
}
```

Now, all that you have to do from the server is to call this function and pass it the message. Since the function belongs to the `MainWindow` class, it will have no problems displaying the message. You can either call it explicitly, or connect a signal to it.